How to exclude classes from being monitored by Sonar for Coverage
Is there a way I could add an attribute on certain classes which I want to be excluded for coverage scan.
I have a lot of repositories which I don't want to do unit tests for them.
Otherwise: how to do this if I know that all repositories will be named like this:
XXXXXQueryRepository.cs
I still want that Sonar will check for code smells and so on on these repository files.


Add System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute to your class
Add CodeCoverage.runsettings file to your solution folder. Example:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="XPlat Code Coverage">
        <Configuration>
          <Format>opencover</Format>
          <SkipAutoProps>true</SkipAutoProps>
          <ExcludeByFile>**/Migrations/*.cs</ExcludeByFile>
          <ExcludeByAttribute>GeneratedCodeAttribute,CompilerGeneratedAttribute</ExcludeByAttribute>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>


Run

dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --logger trx --settings CodeCoverage.runsettings

